# Supply properties file for jar file in Websphere

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have deployed a Spring Web based application in WAS. So WEB-INF/lib contains lot of jar files. One of the jar file trying to load properties file. Means that java file loading test.properties file by using getClassLoader().getResource().

How to supply that test.properties to that jar file ?

Please help me.

Thank you.